# what does " demands forgiveness" mean in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

this is a poem by James. D. Corrothers:

> To be a Negro on a day like this
>   Demands forgiveness.
>   Bruised with blow on blow,
>   Betrayed, like him whose woe dimmed eyes gave bliss,
>   Still must one succor those who brought one low,
>   To be a Negro on a day like this
>
> To be a Negro on a day like this
>   Demands rare patience—patience that can wait
>   In utter darkness. 'Tis the path to miss,
>   And knock, unheeded, at iron gate,
>   To be a Negro on a day like this
>
> To be a Negro on a day like this
>   Demands strange loyalty, we served a flag
>   Which is to us white freedom's emphasis.
>   Ah! One must love when Truth and Justice lag,
>   To be a Negro on a day like this
>
> To be a Negro on a day like this
>   Alas! Lord God, what evil have we done?
>   Still shines the gate, all gold and amethyst,
>   But I pass by, the glorious goal unwon,
>   "Merely a Negro"—on a day like this!!!!!!"

what does "demands forgiveness" mean? i have problem in comprehension.

Comment: Can we have a little more context?  On a day like what?

Comment: yeah, I put whole poem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting poetry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Demands" in this case should be read as "Requires"

In stanza 1, to forgive those to harm you

In stanza 2, to wait patiently

In stanza 3, to be loyal to a flag that isn't totally supporting freedom.